# System of vectors $\{f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n\} \in V^*$ is a basis of $V^*$ if and only if $\ker f_1 \cap \ker f_2 ...\cap \ker f_n = \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm completely new to linear algebra so please bear with me. I need to prove the following:

> Let V be a linear space , dim V = n. Show that the system of vectors {$f_1$, $f_2$, ..., $f_n$} in V* is a basis of V* 
>   if and only if when $kerf_1 \cap kerf_2 ...\cap kerf_n $ = {0}.

'=>' Let the system of vectors {$f_1$, $f_2$, ..., $f_n$} be a basis of V*.  Assume $kerf_1 \cap kerf_2 ...\cap kerf_n $ $=/=$ {0}.

But then $a_1f_1+a_2f_2+...+a_nf_n=0$ for not all $a_1$=0. Thus dimV* <  n which leads to contradiction. Would that suffice as a proof?

Still I don't quite get why do we need the intersection of nullspaces to be {0}. During the lecture we were told that dimV = dim V* no matter the setting. As far as i understand non-zero intersection of kernels would cause some of the aforementioned dimension to be less than n. Could you show me the easiest example why it happens (eg. in $R^2$) ?

Comment: I don't understand your proof for the first direction (how do you show not all $a_i$ are zero?)  Perhaps you should assume they are a basis (so they span) and then form a linear combination that creates a particular function of interest.

Comment: For the other direction, you can use the fact that any collection of $n-1$ or fewer linear functions from $V$ to the 1-dimensional field must have some common non-zero elements of the nullspace, since you can form the linear function $(f_1(x), \ldots, f_{n-1}(x))$ from $n$ dimensions to $n-1$ dimensions with rank at most $n-1$.

Comment: Or you could just argue from the linear function $(f_1(x), \ldots, f_n(x))$ from $n$ dimensions to $n$ dimensions, find out what the nullspace is for this.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Concerning your last answer - how would you describe such a nullspace? I have trouble understadning intersection of kernels in this situation.. To my mind not only does intersection of nullspaces consist of {0} vector but also every single nullspace of $f_i$ . Could you describe the solution more explicitly?

Comment: See my more detailed answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using the word "nullspace" rather than "kernel," but it is the same thing. Here is an example:  Let $V = \mathbb{R}^2$. Let: 
\begin{align*}
f_1(x,y) &= x\\
f_2(x,y) &=y\\
\end{align*}
The individual nullspaces each have an infinite number of elements: 
\begin{align*}
Null(f_1) &= \{(0,y)| y \in \mathbb{R}\}\\
Null(f_2) &= \{(x,0)|x \in \mathbb{R}\}
\end{align*}
So $Null(f_1) \cap Null(f_2) = \{(0,0)\}$. And indeed any linear function $g(x,y)$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a linear combination of $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$:

\begin{align*}
g(x,y) &=g(x(1,0) + y(0,1)) \\
&= xg(1,0) + yg(0,1) \\
&= g(1,0)f_1(x,y) + g(0,1)f_2(x,y)
\end{align*}

So the functions $\{f_1,f_2\}$ span $V^*$.  Also, the function $(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y)) = (x,y)$ is the identity function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, which has full rank. So for any $(w,z) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ there is an $(x,y)$ such that $(f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y)) = (w,z)$.

---

Now how would you prove $\{f_1,f_2\}$ are linearly independent?  You start your proof: "Suppose there are values $a_1,a_2$ such that $a_1f_1(x,y) + a_2f_2(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.  We want to prove that $a_1=a_2=0$." You then proceed by plugging in convenient values of $(x,y)$ into the known equation from the previous sentence.

---

Suppose $h(x) = (f_1(x), \ldots, f_n(x))$.  Since $h(x)$ is a linear function, we immediately know a relationship between $rank(h)$ and the dimension of its nullspace. To understand $Null(h)$,  start by saying "suppose $z$ is in the nullspace of $h(x)$, then...[fill in by using the definition of nullspace]"

To understand $\cap_{i=1}^n Null(f_i)$, start by saying "suppose $z$ is in...[fill in]"

To prove linear independence of $\{f_1, \ldots, f_n\}$ you start by saying "suppose $a_1f_1(x) + \cdots + a_nf_n(x)=0$ for all $x \in V$.  We want to show $a_1=\cdots = a_n=0$." Then proceed by substituting convenient values of $x \in V$ into the known equation.

Answer (score 0):

let $x\neq 0$ then you can extend it to a basis $\{x, a_2,...a_n\}$ define $f(x)=1$ and $f(a_i)=o$ then since $f_i$'s are basis so $\exists j_o$ such that $f_j(x)\neq 0$ so $x\notin \cap kerl f_i$